# Assigning Dynamic SQL Output Variables to Local Variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Setting aside the caveats of using dynamic SQL, I am wondering whether I can dynamically declare which local variable I want to assign the value of a given output variable from a dynamic SQL statement.

I hope I said that well enough. Here's a little bit of the code and where I'm having trouble. I have a stored procedure with a number of OUTPUT parameters, like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mngi_psi_paginate]

 @image_desc_1          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_2          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_3          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_4          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_5          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_6          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_7          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_8          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_9          VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@image_desc_10         VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
```

...

There are a total of 40 OUTPUT parameters. I will be allowing the user to page through an unknown number of images, 10 images at a time. For each image, I need 4 fields of data, but with a potential of 10 records at a time, I'd rather not hardcode all 40 variable assignments.

I realize that there should be better ways to do this, but the receiving application is not a web browser, so unfortunately, this is what I have to work with.

I also do a few other things: determine the total number of images, the number of pages, and the number of images that will be displayed on the page.

Once I figure out which set of images belong on the given page, I put them into a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #images_page   
    (primary_key INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,image_id VARCHAR(36)
    ,image_path VARCHAR(400)
    ,image_type VARCHAR(5)
    ,image_desc VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT INTO     #images_page
SELECT           image_id
                ,image_path
                ,image_type
                ,image_desc
FROM            @images_set
WHERE           primary_key >= @image_start 
AND             primary_key <= @image_end
```

Then I build a string to execute a dynamic SQL statement, which is all wrapped in a WHILE loop, with the hope of being able to assign only the variables that have a corresponding record (e.g., @image_desc_1 gets data from row #1, @image_desc_2 gets data from row #, etc.

```
SELECT  @image_page_total = COUNT(*)
FROM    #images_page

DECLARE      @row_counter INT
            ,@loop_counter INT

SET @loop_counter = @image_page_total
SET @row_counter = 1

WHILE
    @loop_counter > 0
AND @row_counter <= @loop_counter
BEGIN

-- Dynamically assign variables
DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @params     NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @assign     NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @sql =      'SELECT  @image_desc = image_desc ' + 
                    '@image_path = image_path,' +
                    '@image_type = image_type,' +
                    '@image_comments = image_comments' +
                    'FROM #images_page ' + 
                    'WHERE primary_key = ' + CAST(@row_counter AS VARCHAR)

SELECT  @params =   '@image_desc varchar(50) OUTPUT'
SELECT  @assign =   '@image_desc = @image_desc_' + CAST(@row_counter AS VARCHAR) + ' OUTPUT'

--This line works because I've simply typed out the variable name
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_desc = @image_desc_1 OUTPUT
--This line does not work because I am trying to append the '_1' to   @image_desc
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @assign

SET @row_counter = @row_counter + 1

END
```

The first EXEC sp_executesql line works because that's the way it's supposed to work and that's the way you see it in all of the documentation and examples. The second EXEC sp_executesql is what I'd really like to be able to do, but I just can't seem to see the way to do it.

Is there a way to accomplish this the way I am trying to do it?

I am open to alternative methods that would not require me to hardcode the variable assignments.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you need is entirely possible, but perhaps this will guide you in the right direction. It doesn't entirely remove the deed to reference all 40 variable is code, but you don't have to hardcode the variable assignment.

I've used my own example. I've setting the value of @T1 or @T2 depending on the value of @I. So if @I = 1, then @T1 will be set to 'SET AT RUNTIME'. If @I = 2, then @T2 will be set to 'SET AT RUNTIME'. You would need to pass in all 40 variables to your dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @T1     INT,
        @T2     INT,
        @I      VARCHAR(10) = '2',
        @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SET @T' + @I + ' = ''SET AT RUNTIME'''
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@T1 INT OUT, @T2 INT OUT', @T1 OUT, @T2 OUT

SELECT @T1, @T2
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer. I see that I could dynamically construct the variable name in the SQL string, but it doesn't really matter if I can't pass it out dynamically. I'll play with a few other options and let you know what I come up with. I very much appreciate your reply on this. Live long and prosper! I know--you've never heard that one before. Sorry, I couldn't resist. :-)

Comment: What if you return it with a coalesce statement? Then the one that got set dynamically would be the one that gets returned?

Comment: Where are suggesting I do that? In the third parameter of sp_expectutesql or somewhere else?

Comment: Hey, Spock. I'm sorry I couldn't quite see what you were suggesting with COALESCE, but I'm sure it would be far more elegant than what I came up with. I just had to use what worked and move on. Just wanted to come back one more time and say thank you for your response. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spock is correct and I can't dynamically compute the variable that I want to pass out from the dynamic SQL. Someone please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Since I have just the 10 sets of variables to deal with, I sucked it up and just wrote an IF statement for each one. Again, if someone has a better alternative, I am open to anything.

For the record, here is what I did and this works:

```
SET @loop_counter = @image_page_total
SET @row_counter = 1

WHILE
    @loop_counter > 0
AND @row_counter <= @loop_counter
BEGIN

-- Dynamically assign variables
DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @params     NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @assign     NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @sql =      'SELECT @image_path = image_path, ' +
                    '@image_type = image_type, ' +
                    '@image_desc = image_desc, ' +
                    '@image_comments = image_comments ' +
                    'FROM #images_page ' + 
                    'WHERE primary_key = ' + CAST(@row_counter AS VARCHAR)

SELECT  @params =   '@image_path VARCHAR(400) OUTPUT, @image_type VARCHAR(5) OUTPUT, @image_desc VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT, @image_comments VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'

IF @row_counter = 1 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_1 OUTPUT, @image_type_1 OUTPUT, @image_desc_1 OUTPUT, @image_comments_1 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 2 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_2 OUTPUT, @image_type_2 OUTPUT, @image_desc_2 OUTPUT, @image_comments_2 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 3 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_3 OUTPUT, @image_type_3 OUTPUT, @image_desc_3 OUTPUT, @image_comments_3 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 4 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_4 OUTPUT, @image_type_4 OUTPUT, @image_desc_4 OUTPUT, @image_comments_4 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 5 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_5 OUTPUT, @image_type_5 OUTPUT, @image_desc_5 OUTPUT, @image_comments_5 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 6 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_6 OUTPUT, @image_type_6 OUTPUT, @image_desc_6 OUTPUT, @image_comments_6 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 7 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_7 OUTPUT, @image_type_7 OUTPUT, @image_desc_7 OUTPUT, @image_comments_7 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 8 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_8 OUTPUT, @image_type_8 OUTPUT, @image_desc_8 OUTPUT, @image_comments_8 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 9 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_9 OUTPUT, @image_type_9 OUTPUT, @image_desc_9 OUTPUT, @image_comments_9 OUTPUT
IF @row_counter = 10 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @image_type_10 OUTPUT, @image_type_10 OUTPUT, @image_desc_10 OUTPUT, @image_comments_10 OUTPUT

SET @row_counter = @row_counter + 1

END
```